# In DOOM (2016) how do you turn off or disable Developer Mode?

Tags: doom-2016

When I first fired up Doom I toggled GOD mode so I could screw with the AI, but now Doom seems to be stuck in Developer Mode. I can no longer earn achievement and show off my progress.

Whenever an achievement should be awarded the game suggests restarting "without accessing any developer tools to restore.":

[image]

[Shacknews.com](http://www.shacknews.com/article/94650/doom-2016-cheat-codes-and-console-commands-godmode-all-unlocks) suggests the possibility that there is a "Cheat Flag" on my save.

> We’d also like to mention that using any of the commands listed above may trigger a Cheat Flag on your save file, that may or may not disable online play. This is how the system worked in the game’s alpha build, and it may affect players the same way in the final release.

Unfortunately, restarting Doom and not hitting the tilde key does not solve the issue and I can't afford to loose my save as I've already invested 8+ hours. Are there any commands I can run to disable Developer Mode?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could do it without starting a new save.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more futile it feels.

Comment: I may just create a backup of C:\Users\UserName\Saved Games\id Software\DOOM and just delete the save from inside Doom

Comment: I played for a few hours with Steam in Offline Mode and started getting this message. Now that I'm back online I continue to get them.

Comment: So far, deleting the saves seems to be the only sure way to disable developer mode and re-enable achievements on Steam. I've made progress well past my old save, but would still like to test any alternative solutions

Comment: That message in no way implies that "developer mode" is enabled. It says that at some point you used a tool or cheat (e.g. console command), which has tainted your campaign save ("game profile"). However, the last sentence ought to say "Restart *the campaign*..."

Comment: @Yorik i'll upload a screenshot of the console after work. As soon as I would enter campaign from the main menu, the console would have something like DEV_MODE> at the beginning of every new line

Answer (score 1):

It is easy the notice message does say what to do you must delete your save games(game slot) in game in campaign mode then you exit and enter again and start a new game slot

Answer (score 0):

I have found verifying game files in steam fixes this, but its very annoying. I also did not have to restart my save after verifying files and logging back into my save.

Comment: Everything checked out fine, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming you have gone through those basic path, and you will lose all previous saved games):

1. disable cloud sync for DOOM
2. delete all the saves under "Saved Games"
3. create a new game > new campaign

   - please take note, if you have 1 campaign in your previous save, then 1 new save game is sufficient, but if previously you have 2 or 3 saved games, please create the 2nd or 3rd save game (all create from scratch, yes you will lose all the previous saves)
4. now DO NOT quit the game, while you still playing the game (not in menu, but in game)
5. alt tab and Right Click DOOM properties, Enable back the cloud sync
6. wait for it to finish resync (it may take a while, so play the game while waiting)
7. it will force overwrite the previous saves. (as it cannot force download from cloud while you playing the game, but able to upload, it will eventually overwrite it)
8. good luck